# How to show created in admin panel from TimeStampedModel

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, django-model-utils

trying to follow https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/186

```
#admin.py

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.readonly_fields += (
            "created",
            "modified",
        )
```

error

```
django_1        | SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
django_1        | 
django_1        | ERRORS:
django_1        | <class 'meetings.admin.CompanyAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[0]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'CompanyAdmin', or an attribute of 'meetings.Company'.
django_1        | <class 'meetings.admin.CompanyAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[1]' is not a callable, an attribute of 'CompanyAdmin', or an attribute of 'meetings.Company'.
```

How do you show the `created` value in the admin panel with django-model-utils ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like `created` and `modified` are not attributes on your model (`meetings.Company`).

Are you sure you have added these fields to your `Company` model.

If this doesn't solve your problem, can you add your model to the question.

Comment: you're right, I was editing the wrong model :D